# How do I set the caret cursor color on an MDCTextField?

Tags: ios, material-components

I'm using `MDCTextInputControllerFilled` and setting the `activeColor` property changes the underline and the floating placeholder. However, I cannot find a way to set the blinking cursor color, it's blue by default.
Is there a way of changing the color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for using MDC-iOS.

Cursor color has just been [added](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-ios/pull/2297) as a parameter on MDCTextField (.cursorColor).

It was included in the release 38.1.0.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and got around it by subclassing MDCTextField and overriding layoutSubviews to change the tintColor only after the view is laid out. This worked for me.

Ex:

AppaceaTextField.h

```
#import "MaterialTextFields.h"
@interface AppaceaTextField : MDCTextField
@end
```

AppaceaTextField.m

```
#import "AppaceaTextField.h"
@implementation AppaceaTextField
- (void) layoutSubviews{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
@end
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Since [`MDCTextField`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-ios/blob/develop/components/TextFields/src/MDCTextField.h) is a subclass of `UITextField`, you should change the `tintColor` property to change the cursor's color:

```
mdcTextField.tintColor = .red
```

Comment: Thanks, but the cursor color stays the same. There must be something special with `MDCTextField`. `mdcTextField.tintColor = .red` has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

     textfield.tintColor = .red

 }
```

Comment: Yeah, but nothing happens when I do that. There must be some override in `MDCTextField`.

Answer (score 0):

Tried everything else. Nothing works except this:

```swift
let colorScheme = MDCSemanticColorScheme()
colorScheme.primaryColor = .systemBlue // <-- This works in my case
colorScheme.errorColor = .systemRed

let container = MDCContainerScheme()
container.colorScheme = colorScheme

let textField = MDCTextField()
let controller = MDCTextInputControllerUnderline(textInput: textField)
controller.applyTheme(withScheme: scheme)
```

For context:

```
pod 'MaterialComponents/TextFields', '~> 104.0.1'
pod 'MaterialComponents/TextFields+Theming', '~> 104.0.1'
```